# Apollo GraphQL Remote and Local Queries

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm working with apollo local state and hoping for help to better understand it and fix my query

Here is what my local apollo state looks like.

```
cache.writeData({
  data: {
    cart: {
      items: [],
      total: 0,
      __typename: 'CART_INFORMATION'
    },
  }
});
```

Where `item` is an array of objects. Each object is in the form of

```
{
 productId: string,
 quantity: number
}
```

When my cart page loads, i want to fetch more details about my cart to display on the page. Here is my query.

```
export const GET_CART_PRODUCTS_DETAILS = gql`
  query productDetails($productIds: [ID]!) {
    cartProducts(productIds: $productIds) {
      id
      name
      price
      imageUrl
      company
      quantity @client
    }
  }
`;
```

My main concern is here `quantity @client`. Since the `cartProducts` query receives an array of ids, i'm not sure how its going to get the quantity of each product from my local state.

Any help/explanation about how to better structure this is appreciated. I have read the docs, but this use case wasn't covered so i don't know if its supported.

Comment: it's described in docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#local-data-query-flow

Comment: Hey @xadm, thanks for trying to help. But as stated in the question, i read the doc. My particular use case is not covered there.

Comment: leave concerns, try ... is it working for one product? probably it will work for an array ... show resolver or better prepare [example] ... real problem, concerns/doubts are off topic on SO